# p4 edit/submit equivalent in git

Tags: git

Im very familiar with perforce, but recently created a bitbucket account and began using git for my projects at home.

In perforce to open specific file(s) in my default changelist I simply typed:

```
p4 edit file1 file2
p4 submit -d "changelist description" ...
```

Does git have an equivalent that allows users to checkout specific files and submit them as I did in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` doesn't have a notion of changelists the way perforce does, but you can use the index in a similar fashion.  After editing `file1` and `file2` (no command necessary ahead of time):

```
$ git add file1 file2
$ git commit -m "commit message"
```

Will stage and commit just the changes to `file1` and `file2`, leaving unstaged any other changes you've made.